# Finding the maximum order of a modulo n where n is an integer and $(a,n) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n = 2^5 \times 3^3$ and let $a$ be a positive integer that is relatively prime to $n$. I am trying to find the maximum order of $a$ modulo $n$.

First by the Euler-Phi function, $\phi(n)= \phi(2^5) \times \phi(3^3) = 288$ is number of $a$ that is relatively prime with n.
The goal is to find $x$ such that $a^x \equiv 1 \ mod \ 288$.
\begin{align*}
a^x \equiv 1 \ mod \ 228 \Longleftrightarrow a^x \equiv 1 \ mod \ 32 , a^x \equiv 1 \ mod \ 9
\end{align*}
By Euler's theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
a^{16} \equiv 1 \ mod \ 32\\
a^{48} \equiv 1 \ mod \ 32
\end{align*}
and also
\begin{align*}
a^6 \equiv 1 \ mod \ 9\\
a^{48} \equiv 1 \ mod \ 9
\end{align*}
then this shows $(a^{48} - 1)$ is divisible by 32 and 9. Since it is divisible by 32 and 9, it is also divisible by multiplication of 32 and 9, which is 288.

This show the maximum order of $a\ mod\ n$ is 48.

But I have a question, for $a^x \ mod \ 32$ and $a^x \ mod \ 9$, should I factor them as $a^x \ mod \ 2$ and $a^x \ mod \ 3$? If I factored them, the maximum order will be $2$.

Need help on this, thanks.

Comment: See the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which is discussed in many prior answers.